# Add (A,i) to combobox if (M,i) has a value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I've got a problem :

Inside my Excel spreadsheet, I have a ComboBox (from *Developer>insert>form>combobox*)

I want to **populate this combobox with values from the A column IF the same number in the M column has a value**.

What VBA code would I use for it?

See below some that i made up (which obviously doesn't work)

Thanks in advance!

```
For i = 10 To 239
    cell1temp = i
    If Sheets("MASTER SHEET").cell(M, cell1temp).Value <> "" Then
        DropDown35.AddItem "" & Worksheets("MASTER SHEET").Cells(A, cell1temp) & _
        " " & Worksheets("MASTER SHEET").Cells(B, cell1temp)
    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In facts, if you go to see the *Format Control*, in the *Control* tab, you'll see that for the form that you inserted can only take a range as an input for the values proposed in the list.

If you go ahead and use the *Macro recorder*, you'll see that these objects are actually called **DropDown** as seen in the code you posted.

So if you want to stick to that object for a particular reason, you'll have to :

1. Pre-extract the values to add,
2. Paste them in adjacents cells to use the range in the next step,
3. Set the `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Drop Down 35").ListFillRange` with the address of the previous range

---

Now if you can change, to a real **ComboBox** (from Developer>Insert>ActiveX>ComboBox) :

You can use a structure like the one you posted :

```
Dim ValA As String, _
    Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER SHEET")

For i = 10 To 239
    If Ws.Cells(i, "M").Value <> vbNullString Then _
        Ws.Shapes.Range("ComboBox1").AddItem Ws.Cells(i, "A") & " " & Ws.Cells(i, "B")
Next i

Set Ws = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my issue, I thought it would be something simple. I'll have to look at compatibility with some of the ActiveX controls now.